# as3 error #2032 with local xml files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This appears to be a common problem. Still, I've tried every solution that has been proposed and I still get error #2032 when I try to load an xml file.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("/../assets/levels/level_0-1.xml")); //error
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadLevelComplete, false, 0, true);
```

The entire folder of my project has been marked as trusted, I've added -use-network=false to the compiler arguments, and I'm launching the swf in a browser. I've been checking the path for the past 2 days, made multiple dummy files with different paths. Still, I get #2032. Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

It could still be a local security restriction preventing flash from opening the file. Especially Chrome has very strict local testing restrictions.

You can test this by putting everything online on a test server, or on a local server using localhost.